# Angular child route redirect not updating the url path

Tags: angular, routes

I have the following route with a redirect for a child route but the URL path is not updated.

```
RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: MainComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo: '/account/data', pathMatch: 'full',  },
                    {
                        path: "account", 
                        children: [
                            ...AccountPaths,
                        ]
                    },
                   
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: '',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ])
```

As you can see I redirect the default path **''** to child route **/account/data**

The proper view is loaded but the **/account/data** is missing in the url

```
http://localhost:4200
```

instead (what I expect)

```
http://localhost:4200/account/data
```

My question is WHY?

Answer (score 0):

You can check all routing events, add tracing property on imports

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    enableTracing: false,
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt show what's include inside your `AccountPaths` array.
Is there another redirection maybe?